# Execute user-privileged task from elevated application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, uac, privilege-elevation

I have an applicaction which is running with administrative privileges. 
Privileges are escalated automatically using application manifest.

```
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
```

From this app I have to execute some code as a user who started the app, but without elevation.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: You would have to implement a method [to impersonate the current user](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/1250033).

Comment: Impersonation will work, but it may be cleaner to rearchitecture so that the application launches without elevation, creating an elevated copy of itself to perform the admin taks.  (If nothing else, this means that the parent process can pass its PID to the child process on the command line, saving you from trying to figure out which process to impersonate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [impersonation](http://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/) to achieve the desired results. In order to impersonate the current user without a password you need to find another process that the user has ran and get the token from that. Explorer is good for that. [Here](http://amiryonatan.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/impersonating-currentuser_26.html) is full sample code.

Comment: Impersonation requires user password, right? Can I do it without prompting user for password everytime?